# How can I salvage a question that, in retrospect, was a bit dumb?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20847403/945456) I original thought was decent, in retrospect, looks like a bad question. The downvotes and subsequent closure made it pretty clear. Since the community has found the question to be of little value, I'm tempted to delete it, but since I can't I am wondering what I can do to salvage it, and avoid similar blunders in the future.

Also, I'm not entirely sure why this was closed as opinion-based. I asked for

1. A list existing alternative stopwatch like tools (if anything this sounds like it should be closed as OT - favorite tool...)
2. A list of potentials pitfalls in mimicking the given javascript solution

I think both of those have non-subjective answers that could be provided.

I could potentially change the question to something like "Here's my naive code. How can I do this in less lines?", but that'd be more of a code-golf question and possibly OT here. It would, however, match the existing answers better. Is substantially changing the question like that warranted in this case?

Comment: 2 things I noticed: You asked for a recommendation and you asked 2 questions.

Comment: You won't be able to delete it.  It has answers with a positive score.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I am aware of that... thus the request for tips on how to salvage it, and avoid similar blunders in the future ;)

Comment: As much as people will tell you that you shouldn't do this, you'll probably actually have the most success posting an entirely new question.  If your new draft really looks different enough to turn the voting pattern around, than people probably won't be able to tell if they're the same

Comment: @SamIam Yea, I almost don't see the point in editing it because even if it re-opens the question, all the people who down-voted have moved on with life and likely won't change their vote.